# How to find the coordinates of a rectangle shape in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml, rectangles

I would like to draw on the screen a consecutive line, using the rectangle shape. I have modified the thickness of the rectangle shape, so it seems a line, instead of a rectangle. Now, since I would like to draw different rectangle shapes, I need to know the coordinates of the shape so I can adjust them, but the functions that are given, the GetPoint gives me back only a vector that contains two values, when the rectangle has 4 points. Maybe it's a dumb question, but how can I get the coordinates of the shape, and if there have been rotations how can I do that? I read on sfml that the function GetPoint doesn't take in consideration the rotation and things. 
I attach the link of what I would like to do.
So I was thinking to make a list of rectangle shapes, that look lines, generating a random angle for the rotation and then make a function that sets the position as in the picture (Even though, I don't know if my idea is doable, if there is a simpler way, feel free to suggest ideas).

https://imgur.com/a/KUwqn9M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the points of a shape using `getPoint(index)`, with index in range 0 to `Shape::getPointCount()` (should be 4 in your case). You can transform these points further using your custom matrix to get the *real* world position.

```
sf::Shape myShape = /* ... */;
sf::Transform matrix = /* could be myShape.getTransform() */;
for (int i = 0; i < myShape.getPointCount(); ++i) {
    const auto pointInModelSpace = matrix.transformPoint(myShape.getPoint(i));
}
```

Comment: Question, if instead I  do for (int i=0; i< shape.getPointCount(); i = i+1) {                               std::cout << shape.getPoint(i) << std::endl; }                                                                            would be that wrong? I don't understand the matrix thing, is it a container that saves the transformation of the shape?

Comment: Okay, I tried to make run the std::cout << shape.getPoint(i) and doesn't work, so I guess it's needed the matrix.

Comment: `sf::Vector2f` has no overloaded operator for `cout`, you need to print the values `x` and `y` individually. Otherwise your loop is correct. `sf::Shape` derives from `sf::Transformable`, which stores the local model matrix for each shape (modified by `setPosition` etc.). You should check out the sfml documentation.